# Differentiate requests originating from different clients in OAuth2 framework of springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have 3 different clients say mobile, web, iot. I am using `grant_type = password` and obtaining accessToken. I get requests `GET /access/resource` from all the clients. I want to process them differently based on their client ID. I know `/oauth/check_token` reponds with client_id but how to extract it in resource server

Answer (score 0):

Use JWT, when authorization server creates token, default `AccessTokenConverter` implementation `DefaultAccessTokenConverter`'s `convertAccessToken` method does: `"response.put(this.clientIdAttribute, clientToken.getClientId());"` for the token to also include client id. Above mentioned `response` is just a hashmap which will be converted to JWT.

When your resource server gets hit on `GET /access/resource`:

```
@RequestMapping("/access/resource")
public @ResponseBody Map<String,Object> getRes() throws IOException {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String,Object> map = objMapper.convertValue(auth.getDetails(),Map.class);
    Jwt jwt = JwtHelper.decode((String) map.get("tokenValue"));
    Map<String,Object> claims = objMapper.readValue(jwt.getClaims(),Map.class);

    // This is what you want
    String clnt_id = (String) claims.get("client_id"); <<------- here

    // your logic here based on clnt_id
    // ex: if(clnt_id.equals("Specific client"){}
     ...

    return Collections.emptyMap();;
}
```

**OR**

`OAuth2Request` also includes resolved client id:

```
Authentication auth = 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String cliend_id = ((OAuth2Authentication) auth).getOAuth2Request().getClientId()
```

This option can be applied even if JWT is not used as Oauth2request is always there.

Take a look here to understand better:

[image: See client ids]